# Wordpress over https on apache and ubuntu not working on vanilla setup

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, https

My configuration:

LInux Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS amd64
apache2       2.4.29-1ubuntu4.11
mysql-server  5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
php           7.2+60ubuntu1 
php7.2-common 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

wordpress 5.3.2–hr

Server almost default install, WP default install, wp-config.phph basic.

Set apache configuration of virtual host for http and https.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        <Directory /var/www/test>
                Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test
     <Directory /var/www/test>
        Options -Indexes
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file empty

Right after installation when I access WP by https – https://test.domain.com I get frontend (default 2020 theme applied), login  and admin area totally messed up, like no CSS exists.

I tried this solution for admin area:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
// so check for https existence
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

but results are same - seems there is no CSS.

When I add lines:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://test.domain.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://test.domain.com' );
```

to wp-config.php I get error message:

The page isn’t redirecting properly

I searched many sites and tried many solutions but I'm stuck now. 
I would like to get working at least admin and login areas.

Comment: Did you use the /wp-admin/install.php tool? Are you sure your file permissions for www-data are sufficient for every file/directory in the root folder?

Comment: After days and days of torture it suddenly works. Only thing I changed is that I commented every default line in .htaccess so it's as empty now.